# как обратиться к переменной в функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

как обратиться к переменной в функции?

например есть код:

```
def func1():
  a = Label(text='aaa')
a.destroy()
```

Но это выведет ошибку, так как же обратиться к этой переменной?

Comment: Никак. Либо объявляйте переменную в нужной области видимости, либо возвращайте её из функции.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Для начала, если вы хотите использовать библиотеку Tkinter, нужно её импортировать и создать окно. Это делается так:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

Затем мы создаём эту переменную в функции, перед этим объявив её глобальной:

```py
def func1():
    global a
    a = Label(text = 'aaa')
```

А затем, мы можем выполнить действие с ней за пределами функции, например, разместить её с помощью метода pack().

```py
a.pack()
```

В конце обязательно пишем:

```py
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Глобальные переменные - зло. Необходимость использовать оператор `global` - это сигнал, что с вашим кодом что-то не так.

Comment: В самом вопросе заложен неправильный ход мысли. Топикастер пытается сделать что-то не так. Подсказать, как это сделать, навряд ли лучшее решение. Например, измените функцию, чтобы  она возвращала значение.

Answer (score 5):

> как обратиться к переменной в функции?

Одно из важных свойств функции - скрывать свою реализацию, т.е. нет необходимости знать как она работает внутри. Если появилась потребность лишить её этого, значит функция в этом месте не нужна:

```py
a = Label(text='aaa')
a.destroy()
```

Чтобы пользоваться функцией, необходимо знать только её имя, её аргументы, и что она возвращает в результате:

```py
def createLabel (text):
    a = Label (text=text)
    return a

a = createLabel ('my label')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def lol1():
    a = Label(text = 'aaa')
    return a
    # вернуть а
def lol2():
    global a
    a.config(text = 'text')
    # изменить текст
    # объявить а глобальной и изменять ее
```

Comment: Для вызова `a.config(text = 'text')` не нужно объявлять `a` глобальной переменной в функции, т.к. эта операция не заменяет значение в этой переменной. А вот откуда в вашем коде глобальная переменная может взяться - не видно. Так что ваш ответ ничего не объясняет, ну и идея с глобальной переменной уже есть в принятом ответе.

Answer (score -2):

```py
def func1():
    func1.a = Label(text='aaa')

func1.a.destroy()
```

Но это **очень** плохая практика.

---

[Чтиво по теме](https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/nested-function-scope-of-variable-closures-in-pyth/).

Comment: Один совет другого хлеще... Передача данных через атрибут функции - это мало того, что глобальное, так ещё и неявное состояние.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Но ведь человеку нужно именно это, как я понял. То что у него архитектура плохая это уже другой вопрос.